# Unable to ssh into Ubuntu 12.04 LTS [could not resolve hostname (hostname): Name or service not known

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm just starting with a clean install of Ubuntu Server 12.04. I've run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I've added the following to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       (hostname)
```

The file previously contained:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       (hostname).hsd1.(state).(ISP).net        (hostname)

# The following....
...
```

I was only able to save edits to that file once I became root [by: `su -l`]. I'm able to ssh with username@ip. However, I'd like to be able to ssh with @hostname

What am I missing?

My goal is to set up a simple LAMP Web Server for PHP website testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the `@hostname` to ssh to another host. That's only required if you'd like to `ssh` as some other user than the one you're currently logged into, on your local machine.

#### Example

```
$ whoami
saml

$ hostname
grinchy
```

If I just `ssh <remotehost>` to some other computer I'll be implicitly trying to login to `<remotehost>` as user `saml`.

Perhaps this user is or isn't also a user on `<remotehost>`. You have to know this ahead of time. So rather than rely on a username being the same on multiple systems, people typically explicitly include this info in their connection commands when using `ssh`.

```
$ ssh someuser@remotehost
```

If you're positive the local user is the same across systems then you can use this:

```
$ ssh remotehost
```

#### .ssh/config file

If you find you have lots of different usernames and remote hosts that you have to login to you can make use of `ssh`'s `config` file. This file is typically in your `$HOME` directory. This file needs to be manually created so it may not even exist. Here's a sample file:

```
# web server
Host webby webby.mydom.com
    User someuser
    Hostname webby.mydom.com
```

With this stanza in your `config` file you can now just `ssh` to the host `webby` and it will automatically use the username `someuser` by default.

```
$ ssh webby
```

You're still able to override this, for example:

```
$ ssh someotheruser@webby
```